# Loggin with G+ only for a comunity

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to start a project where to use the app you need to be in a comunnity of G+.

SO I thought in different ways to do it:

- Send registration and wait until and "admin" gives you permission
- Use Loggin with G+, and then ask for validation
- USe Loggin with G+, and see if you are in a concrete community, and let you log in or not.--> That solution will be perfect, but I don't know if is it possible to do.

So my question is:

Taking care that first 2 options are possible, I want to know if the third one can be done. And if is it possible, where can I find info? (I didn't see anything)

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently an API to identify what communities a Google+ user is in. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9).